# mod_rewrite: redirect does not work as it should

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I need to do this: when someone type `https://mydom1.re.it/sso_mio/<whatever>`, I need to redirect to `https://mydom2.re.it/sso_mio/<whatever>`. So, in ssl.conf file, in mydom1. re.it section, i have the following:

```
<VirtualHost 192.xxx.yyy.zzz:443>   
ServerName mydom1.re.it
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
RewriteEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
SSLCertificateFile ...
SSLCertificateChainFile ...
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 600
RewriteRule ^(sso_mio.*) https://mydom2.re.it [R=301,L]
ProxyPass / http://mydom1.re.it/
ProxyPassReverse / http://mydom1.re.it/
ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/mydom1/mydom1_ssl_error_log 86400"
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/mydom1/mydom1_ssl_access_log 86400" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But it does not work, it does not do the redirection. Can you tell me why, please?

This tester http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ says that the redirection is fine.

Comment: Please format the text properly. It is extremely hard to read it as it is.

Comment: Is the space in your server name in the "httpd.conf"?

Comment: no space on it, i cannot post more than 2 links/urls yet, so i had to add a space.  sorry   :(
there is not space, now i edited the post, so it should look fine  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try your rewriterule like this.

```
RewriteRule ^sso_mio/([^/]+) https://mydom2.re.it/sso_mio/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please elaborate on why this fix should work. Someone flagged your post for it.

Comment: @AndyG Because he said he wanted to redirect from his subdirectory `sso_mio` on mydom1 to the equivalent on mydom2.

Comment: mine mistake in writing the code above, now it's correct.
it does not work.